# How to add line numbers to my Algorithm in Latex

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering

I am writing an algorithm. I am already using the following packages for algorithms:

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

I am also using the `\STATE` tag. I tried to add the package  `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` it started giving errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments.

Comment: add a compilable document ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

The `algorithmic` environment takes an optional argument. The optional argument is a number that defines the skip between line numbering. The default `[0]` implies no line numbering, while `[1]` puts a line number on every line. `[2]` puts a line number every second line, and so forth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \IF{some condition is true}
      \STATE do some processing
    \ELSIF{some other condition is true}
      \STATE do some different processing
    \ELSIF{some even more bizarre condition is met}
      \STATE do something else
    \ELSE
      \STATE do the default actions
    \ENDIF
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \IF{some condition is true}
      \STATE do some processing
    \ELSIF{some other condition is true}
      \STATE do some different processing
    \ELSIF{some even more bizarre condition is met}
      \STATE do something else
    \ELSE
      \STATE do the default actions
    \ENDIF
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[2]
    \IF{some condition is true}
      \STATE do some processing
    \ELSIF{some other condition is true}
      \STATE do some different processing
    \ELSIF{some even more bizarre condition is met}
      \STATE do something else
    \ELSE
      \STATE do the default actions
    \ENDIF
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```